# What could be the expression "double (f)(double)" in C mean

Tags: c

Like I already wrote in the title I have the problem that I need to understand what `double (f)(double)` could mean in C. The whole methode header looks like this:

```
Bmp* drawGraph(double (f)(double),double minX,double maxX)
```

It's for a university project an my professor likes to be absent or not reachable through email or other ways of communication.

I think the name and so the propose of the methode is pretty much self-explaining.

In the letter of information to this method was said that "f" should be a function but I don't know what kind of parameter I should give the method in that case.

```
Bmp* drawGraph(double (f)(double),double minX,double maxX)
{
    double height = f(maxX);

    Bmp* bmp = newBmp(maxX, f(maxX) * 2);

    background(bmp, BLACK);

    //Hier zeichne ich das Koordinatensystem
    //in seiner minimalistischten Form

    drawLine(bmp, GREEN, 0, f(maxX), maxX, f(maxX));
    drawLine(bmp, GREEN, 0, 0, 0, f(maxX) * 2);

    for(double d = minX; d < maxX; d += 0.1)
    {
            drawLine(bmp, RED, d, f(d) + height, d + 0.1, f(d + 0.1) + height);
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
double (f)(double)
```

`f` is a parameter of function type: a function that has a `double` parameter and that returns  a `double` value.

For example:

```
double foo(double a)
{
    return a + 42.0;
}
```

The parameter is adjusted (and therefore the declaration is equivalent) to a pointer to a function that has a `double` parameter and that returns  a `double` value.

```
double (*f)(double)
```

So these declarations are all equivalent:

```
void bla(double (f)(double));
void bla(double f(double));
void bla(double (*f)(double));
```

Comment: @Akkyen Just remember: You can't insert a function declaration there, you have to declare the function elsewhere and put a *pointer* to that function (using the `&` operator) in a place that expects such an expression.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Will keep that in mind and also a big thanks for the quick respond

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: There is no need for `&` operator as function's name decays to pointer itself.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Good to know! My C is rusty, apparently. I mainly wanted to highlight that you don't put a declaration in there but, rather, an expression containing the name of the function.